# More pseudoholomorphic curves than complex valued functions

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, pseudo-holomorphic-curves

A lecture I heard had a remark - "There is a rich class of pseudohoplomorphic curves to a symplectic manifold with an almost complex structure (tamed by the symplectic structure).  On the other hand, there are very few complex valued functions on a symplectic manifold".  Can someone explain why?  Or point me to some reference?  I always wondered why people do not study complex valued functions -that should be equally insightful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that, instead of complex-valued functions $f:M\to\mathbb{C}$ you mean *$J$-holomorphic functions*, i.e., complex-valued functions $f:M\to\mathbb{C}$ that satisfy $f'(x)(Jv) = i\,f'(x)(v)$ for all $v\in T_xM$.  The complex-valued functions don't have anything to do with the almost-complex structure $J$, while the $J$-holomorphic functions clearly do.

The reason these latter aren't usually interesting on an almost-complex manifold is that, while the equations for pseudoholomorphic curves form a *determined* elliptic system (and so have plenty of local solutions), the equations for $J$-holomorphic functions form an *overdetermined* PDE system when the domain has (real) dimension greater than $2$, and the integrability of the underlying almost complex structure is exactly the condition that this overdetermined system be 'maximally compatible'.  In fact, for most almost-complex manifolds $(M^{2n},J)$ of real dimension $2n>2$, the sheaf of $J$-holomorphic functions on $M$ is just the sheaf of constant functions, so there is nothing special to say about it.

Comment: Indeed, what I had in mind were J-holomorphic functions.  Thanks for the answer